# Access @user from another model (not current_user) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The setup:

(This is just a summary, so don't mind minor typos)

I have a model Deviceentry with many deviceentries that need a default scope applied. Another model, Sandbox, has many sandboxes that define what users should be able to access the deviceentries (as well as other restrictions on date, etc.)  These Sandboxes are user defined is why I made them a separate model.

So now I need to write a default scope for Deviceentry that restricts *all* access it based on the sandboxes.  I know it will be along the lines of:

```
def self.default_scope
  Sandbox.each do |sandbox|
    # compare sandbox entries with deviceentry attributes
    .
    .
    @user.email == sandbox.email #pseudocode
  end
end
```

I've got most of them planned out - but the problem here, is the one particular comparison I noted. I need to compare the Sandbox's "email" entry, with @user.email. It has to be @user, not current_user (I have admins that pose as other users, so @user != current_user for those cases, and they need to see the exact same deviceentry data as the @user).

Any suggestions on how to approach this?  I've been scratching my head for hours with no progress.

Comment: You are mixing Model functions (scope/searching) with controller functionality (restricting access / routing). Create named scope "for_user" that will accept user parameter and use it in controller. You can go with "cancancan" gem to create abilities easily and restrict access.

Comment: That would probably involve a full site redesign, as I already have devise set up and it is a full blown website. Is there any other way? I'd rather not have to make this a two week project.

Comment: Cancancan works with devise so you could skip the redesign.

Comment: I decided to just use current_user instead and build a workaround for the admins. Thanks for the advice though.